# Transpose Symbol with Solution

Tags: linear-algebra

all!

I'm working on some homework problems from my linear algebra class and we're solving just basic matrix equations, but the solutions have what look like transpose symbols attached to the solution set.  I'm getting the correct solutions, I'm just not sure why the symbol is there.  If you could enlighten me, I'd be most appreciative!

Example Question:
Consider the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&2&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$, and let us solve the equation $A\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ (usually written $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} \in \mathbb{R}^3$).

Solution to Example Question:
$\left\{(s,0,0)^T : s \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$.

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: It would be nice if you copy the problem and insert it inline.

Comment: Hi, Shailesh. You're right, that would have been better, but this is my first post so I'm still learning how to navigate and use the site.

Comment: No problem. This was just a suggestion to be remembered as you use this site more and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my two-cents.

It looks like the are wanting the solution written as a column vector, but in the manual (or the solutions part of the text) they are trying to save space so they write the solution as the transpose of a row vector. (note: the transpose of a row vector is a column vector)

Comment: You know what, that makes perfect sense, I think you're spot on!  Thanks so much, that was very helpful, J.D.!